# Arraylist<> is null although it's initialized in the constructor

Tags: java, json, arraylist, constructor

I'm made a small `httpserver` in java and as you know it should be all static and I needed a small database so decided to make an in-memory one. The problem is the database class should be static to use it inside of server.

So I changed my mind and trying to store the data in json file and everytime the data is needed, just read it from the file. To make it short I need to use an arraylist. it's initialized in the constructor. but  when it comes to use it, it's null :|

This is my code:

```
public class DbContext {

private ArrayList<Player> players;

public DbContext() {
    this.players = new ArrayList<>();
    readPlayer();
}

public Player getPlayerByIds(long id, long boardId) {
    for (Player p : players) {
        if (p.getBoardId() == boardId && p.getId() == id) {
            writePlayer();
            return p;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

public boolean updatePlayer(Player player) {
    for (Player p : players) {
        if (p.getId() == player.getId()) {
            p = player;
            writePlayer();
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public void addPlayer(Player player) {
    players.add(player);
    writePlayer();
}

private boolean playerExists(Player player) {
    for (Player p : players) {
        if (p.getId() == player.getId()) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

private void readPlayer() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("players.json"));
        if (br.read() > 0) {
            players = gson.fromJson(br, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Player>>() {
            }.getType());
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DbContext.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DbContext.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private void writePlayer() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("players.json")) {
        gson.toJson(players, writer);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DbContext.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks guys

Comment: You are assigning a value to it in - `players = gson.fromJson(br, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Player>>() {}.getType());` - perhaps that value is null.

Comment: based on @Eran's comment, make the `players` member `final` and use `List.clear()` and `List.addAll()` that way you'll probably get a NullPointerException, but you then know where your problem probably lies

Comment: yes don't init your arraylist in constructor, its not necessary because you override it with line players = gson.fromJson..it just pollute the memory... debug your code and check the return value of getType

Comment: Better use private List readPlayer() {.. return list;} . It is re-usable for outside class too.

Comment: @SumeshTG the problem here is not the design ;) i think he just want to know why he have nullpointer, design come after :D

Comment: Yes, the poor design is the problem because it hides the intent and leads to bugs.

Comment: @Eran Tried to avoid this by checking the `BufferedReader` size but I think I'm doing it wrong. Any suggestion?

Comment: Use parser for return json file as array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to "Adriaan Koster" and "Sumesh TG", I found the solution finally. It appears that gson couldn't transform the json to my class. So i decided to pars it manually.

```
String currentLine;
List<Player> playerList = new ArrayList<>();
while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    Player p = new Gson().fromJson(currentLine, Player.class);
    System.out.println(p.toString());
    playerList.add(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably just not finding the file. If you put the file in a source root (for example `src/main/resources/` in a standard maven project) then you can read it from the classpath using

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(PLAYERS_FILE);
```

I would refactor the code a bit, for example:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DbContext {

    // use constants, not String literals
    public static final String PLAYERS_FILE = "players.json";

    // use interfaces where possible rather than concrete implementation type
    private List<Player> players;

    public DbContext() {
        // the initialization was always overwritten
        // just assign directly from the method
        this.players = readPlayers();
    }

    public Optional<Player> getPlayerByIds(long id, long boardId) {
        for (Player p : players) {
            if (p.getBoardId() == boardId && p.getId() == id) {
                // no need to write players here since there is no change
                // writePlayers();
                return Optional.of(p);
            }
        }
        // do not return null from a method, use Optional instead
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    public void updatePlayer(Player player) {

        // this will not work. player will not get added in the list if you reassign a local variable
        // for (Player p : players) {
        //    if (p.getId() == player.getId()) {
        //        p = player;

        Optional<Integer> playerIndex = findPlayer(player);
        if (playerIndex.isPresent()) {
            players.set(playerIndex.get(), player);
        } else {
            // if the player is not found you can either add the player
            addPlayer(player);
            // ... or throw an exception
            // throw new DbContextException(String.format("Could not find player to update: %s", player));
            // returning a boolean to indicate failure is sort of evil
        }
    }

    private Optional<Integer> findPlayer(Player player) {
        for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
            if (players.get(i).getId() == player.getId()) {
                return Optional.of(i);
            }
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    public void addPlayer(Player player) {
        // if you want players to be unique in the list, you should do some checking here
        players.add(player);
        writePlayers();
    }

    // never used
//    private boolean playerExists(Player player) {
//        for (Player p : players) {
//            if (p.getId() == player.getId()) {
//                return true;
//            }
//        }
//        return false;
//    }

    // refactored methods below so each method does only one thing, or at least operates at a single level of abstraction

    private List<Player> readPlayers() {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(PLAYERS_FILE))) {
            return readPlayers(br);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // DbContextException extends RuntimeException
            throw new DbContextException(String.format("Could not read players from %s", PLAYERS_FILE), e);
        }
    }

    private List<Player> readPlayers(BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
        List<Player> players;
        if (br.read() > 0) {
            players = readPlayersAvailable(br);
        } else {
            players = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return players;
    }

    private List<Player> readPlayersAvailable(BufferedReader br) {
        List<Player> players;
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        // this looks hacky. in Gson 2.8.0 you can use TypeToken.getParameterized(ArrayList.class, Player.class).getType()
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Player>>() {
        }.getType();
        players = gson.fromJson(br, type);
        return players;
    }

    private void writePlayers() {
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(PLAYERS_FILE)) {
            writePlayers(writer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new DbContextException(String.format("Could not write players to %s", PLAYERS_FILE), e);
        }
    }

    private void writePlayers(FileWriter writer) throws IOException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        gson.toJson(players, writer);
        writer.flush();
    }
}
```

It looks to me like the code in readPlayersAvailable is not working. I suggest taking a look at Gson (maybe switch to a more recent version) and check if your file is actually found by the fileReader.

Comment: Thanks man. that looks awesome but still does not work. It's probably the reading from file.

Comment: Actually it seems the reading part is fine but can't cast to my custom object. @Adriaan

Comment: Could be. We would need more information about the Player class, the JSON in your file and the exceptions you are getting to help you with that.